# Which crawled property for last modifiers account name or email address?

Tags: fast-search, managed-property, crawled-property

We have FAST Search 2010 in use.

There is the managed property `ModifiedBy` which tells who has modified an element. This managed property equals to the name of the Person, e.g. Doe, Jon.

I want to get the account name and/or the email address of the person who has last modified the element.

I have created managed properties who are each mapped to one of the following crawled properties. None of them return the email or the account name.

```
 Property Set                         | Property Name           | Variant Type
===============================================================================
 00130329-0000-0130-c000-000000131346 | ows_Modified            | 31
 00130329-0000-0130-c000-000000131346 | ows_ModifiedBy          | 31
 00130329-0000-0130-c000-000000131346 | ows_Modified_x0020_By   | 31
 00130329-0000-0130-c000-000000131346 | ows_Last_x0020_Modified | 31
 f29f85e0-4ff9-1068-ab91-08002b27b3d9 | #8 (Office:8)           | 31
 f29f85e0-4ff9-1068-ab91-08002b27b3d9 | #8 (Office:8)           | 30
 d5cdd502-2e9c-101b-9397-08002b2cf9ae | #8 (Office:8)           | 31
 0f451d82-37a2-4831-a5d7-e5d57c3ad793 | editor                  | 31
```

I have turned on the FFDumper and looked into the dump files. They do not contain any email adresses or account names.

**Which crawled property contains the email address or the account name of the last modifier?**

If there is none then I have to build such a crawled property by myself. The `Modified By` column's raw value in a list item looks like `<user id>;#<name of person>`. My idea is to build a new custom item processor which emits a new crawled property that contains the account name. For that the custom item processor needs the raw data and with the help of the SharePoint API the `SPUser` object with the right ID can be fetched.

Since the `Modified By` column's internal name is `editor` I have looked for a crawled property named `ows_editor` but there isn't any. The crawled property `editor` mentioned above is empty.

**Which of the crawled properties contains the raw data of the Modified By column?**